# Can't stream videos even though I have a fast Internet connection

Tags: networking, video, streaming

For some reason, despite having an internet connection that should easily handle it, I seem to be unable to stream HD videos from beginning to end.

Specifically, I usually attempt to stream videos from [Crunchyroll](http://crunchyroll.com), but have had some (although fewer) problems with YouTube/Hulu as well. I can usually get through about 8 minutes of a video before it freezes and requires me to refresh the page. It’ll then play another ~8 minutes before another refresh. I’ve also had problems (although once again, fewer) attempting to stream 480p or even 360p videos.

I know my Internet connection is capable of it, because while I had a WUBI (Windows-based Ubuntu Installer) installation of Ubuntu, everything streamed perfectly. I also have the same problem over a wired connection, which is much faster. Hardware shouldn’t be an issue either.

Wireless [SpeedTest](http://www.speedtest.net/my-result/3036342747):

- **Download:** 70.32Mb/s
- **Upload:** 38.82Mb/s
- **Ping:** 13 ms

Wired [SpeedTest](http://www.speedtest.net/my-result/2956013524):

- **Download:** 854.15Mb/s
- **Upload:** 199.43Mb/s
- **Ping:** 3 ms

Specs:

- **CPU:** Intel Core i7 2760QM 2.4GHz
- **GPU:** AMD Radeon 6990M
- **RAM:** 4 GB DDR3 RAM

Problem presents itself using either integrated or discrete graphics.

Comment: If it was a connection speed problem, then you'd have to wait until the video buffers. If you have to refresh, then it looks more like the download is interrupted for some reason.

Comment: Yeah. I thought as much as well. I'm not sure why that would happen, though. Maybe some misbehaving software on my computer? Maybe I should try uninstalling steam and all the games I have on it (some have DRM, which is the only thing I can think that would cause this).

Comment: Do you control QoS at your institution?

Comment: Just making sure - is your Flash the latest version?

Comment: I am not sure if we have QoS. Is there any way to check? It shouldn't really matter, though, as everyone around me can stream fine, and I could in Ubuntu. My flash is the latest version.

Comment: If is it a buffering issue, then you might clean your computer from browsing history, updating browser or use different one Chrome, Firefox are good choices. If still appears, try to stream using HTML5 player rather than Flash Player. and disable hardware acceleration from browser options. Also, check speedguide.net TCP Optimizer, use it to optimize your connection settings. one or more of these methods will solve your problem I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Shots in the dark but hey!

Could try using a different browser. FireFox vs Chrome vs Opera.

What version of windows are you running? Assuming windows. Maybe a windows update will do the trick?

The only other things I can thing: Video Card, Memory or maybe the hard drive. You would have to get a diagnostics program to verify those.

Are you doing any sort of overclocking? If so, that would be the first thing I would roll back.

Good luck! Sorry I didn't have anything like 'replace file A and you will be fine'

Comment: I've tried different browsers (with different versions of flash), and all they all behave the same.

I am running Windows 7 Ultimate edition. 

Where would I find a program to verify those things? The HD is an SSD that performs quite well, and I play games with the GPU without issue.

No overclocking. As much as I've wanted to try it, I've always been scared. 

Thank you for attempting to help. I'll look into those diagnostic programs.

Comment: Normally that answer is Norton! But I haven't needed one in so long. Google & Toms Hardware would be my recommendations there. You just never know. Could be a Codec issues. Make sure windows updates are all on the up and up. Grabbing the latest DirectX doesn't hurt. Lastly, take a look at the programs you have installed under UNINSTALL PROGRAMS. YOU JUST never know where something you install clobbered something else :/.  Your welcome.

Comment: I'm not sure how I'd fix a codec issue. Any ideas?

I've got all the important Windows Updates installed, but on the optional side, there is an Intel Graphics driver available. I had previously installed it, but it kept my computer from waking from sleep, so I rolled it back. The problem was also not solved by it. Other than that, just language packs.
I should have the latest Direct X, but I'll make sure. I've uninstalled almost everything that could cause a problem, I think. Here is everything I have installed: http://i.imgur.com/tsfiwoC.png Anything you think I should get rid of?

Comment: Here is something. Have you tried it in SafeMode with Networking? that's a total guess hehe

Comment: The issue seems to occur in safe mode as well. I made it 12:27 into the video before a refresh was required.

Comment: If you think the Hardware is fine there is always the reinstall windows option. Remember ever if the Hardware is new doesn't mean it's error free. You could try Knoppix linux. You can run it right from a CD. Could help to rule out HW issues. ON THE BRIGHT SIDE!! Windows 8.1 tomorrow haha.. =)

Comment: I used a WUBI installation of Ubuntu for a while, and I had no problems there. I don't think it is a hardware problem. Maybe I'll reinstall Windows when I get the chance (I don't have the installation media with me right now). Windows 8.1 may also be a good option.

Comment: Good luck my friend!! I feel your pain when it comes to WTH windows errors

Comment: Thank you for all the help. I hope a reinstall helps when I get around to it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try looking at the network adapter power settings in **Network and Sharing Center**.

1. Open **Network and Sharing Center**
2. Click **Change adapter settings** down the left
3. Right click your network adapter
4. Click **Properties**
5. Click **Configure** button
6. Click the **Power Management** tab
7. Untick all the configurable power options
8. Click **OK**
9. Close **Network and Sharing Center**
10. I'd recommend restarting the computer
11. Test

Sample image of screen to amend:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

To answer the codec question :
Back when all sorts of dodgy movie websites each used slightly different codecs to try for best compression (seems more standardised now) the answer was k-lite  codecs as they didn't have all the adware and junk of most codec packs.

They seem to still exist. https://www.codecguide.com/download_kl.htm
Still, be cautious and check for adware and viruses before installing.

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question. It's not a codec issue. If it was the video would not play at all.